# Automorphism for definable set

Tags: logic, model-theory

In $(\mathbb{R},<)$
$D_{1}:=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}|\,x<y\}
 , D_{2}:=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}|\,x=y\}
 , D_{3}:=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}|\,y<x\}
  D_{4}:=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}|\,x\neq y\},
  D_{5}:=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}|\,x\leq y\}
 , D_{6}:=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}|\,y\leq x\}
 , D_{7}=\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$
 , and $D_{8}:=\emptyset $

I want to Show none of else is definable in $(\mathbb R,<)$.  Using Hint: 
 . Using if h is an automorphism, then it preserves setwise,i.e. h[D]=D.

And hint also says, first check that if D
  is definable in $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$
 , then for i=1,2,3
 . $D\cap D_{i}\neq\emptyset$
  iff $D_{i}\subseteq D$

And left hand side is done. The problem is r.h.s.

For doing $\Rightarrow $, I need an automorphism $h$ which preserves <  and for any $(x,y) \in D_i$, and for (a,b) in $D_i\cap D$,  $ (h(a),h(b))=(x,y)$ so that $D_i\subseteq D$. But I couldn't find such automorphism.

Comment: By the way, this question is basically a better version of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1467039/some-questions-about-first-order-logic - but of course you knew that.

Comment: none of else ?????

Comment: @PatrickStevens I knew it. And also, there's my question before on same problem. But I think that the question in your link is somewhat different to mine. Sorry for my repetitive similar question on this site...

Comment: If this is a duplicate, then it's a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1461166/definable-binary-relations-in-mathbbr/1461259#1461259, not the one cited in Patrick Stevens' comment which doesn't mention automorphisms and has an answer that does not answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: the affine function $h(x) = \alpha x + \beta$, where $\alpha, \beta \in \Bbb{R}$ and $\alpha > 0$ is strictly order-preserving, i.e., an automorphism of $(\Bbb{R}, <)$. Given $(x, y) \in D_i$, $(a, b) \in D_i \cap D$, use what that tells you about $x, y, a$ and $b$ to find $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $(h(a), h(b)) = (x, y)$.